# Error executing task write() argument must be str, not bytes | MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After a clean install of Windows 10 when I started to use MySQL workbench I have this error when I try to dump a database.

I could not find anything about it anywhere, the only thing I find are problems with phyton, but nothing related with Workbench.

Output after dumping a database:

```
08:29:00 Dumping foo(all tables)
Error executing task write() argument must be str, not bytes
08:29:01 Export of b'C:\\Users\\erick\\Documents\\dumps\\Dump20210121 (2).sql' has finished
```

And the output file is in blank, some ideas?

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102320

Comment: Fixed in [8.0.25](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/commit/e202a988fc22703c32cea70c214b5a6183b8739a).

Answer (score 35):

You can disable (uncheck) the option **create schema**.  It is annoying but it works.

Comment: MySql Workbench is full of surprises

Comment: Also annoying: having the whole backup fail on the target system because "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database" because there was no CREATE SCHEMA.

Comment: Yeah! this saved me from the annoying problem. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I just closed MySQL Workbench and reloaded it and the problem went away. Win 10, Workbench 8.0.23.

Answer (score 20):

If you have  the latest MySQL Workbench  (8.0.23), just uninstall and install MySQL Workbench 8.0.20. That worked for me.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 20.1 and downgrading fixed this issue.

Comment: This! Solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Solved on Windows version of Workbench.

Comment: Just had this issue in version 8.0.23 and updated to 8.0.25 (which is currently the latest version). Now the issue disappeared, and the export is created fine (with CREATE statements)

Comment: Downgrading is not always possible, you can try to do that on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 11):

Another workaround to this issue is to edit [`wb_admin_export.py`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/plugins/wb.admin/frontend/wb_admin_export.py).

In `dump_to_folder` (line [1679](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/5e10b42aa539155128bd97d54ed2cdd7ca283b34/plugins/wb.admin/frontend/wb_admin_export.py#L1679)) replace

```py
self.out_pipe = open(path,"w")
```

with

```py
self.out_pipe = open(path,"wb")
```

In `dump_to_file` (line [1957](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/5e10b42aa539155128bd97d54ed2cdd7ca283b34/plugins/wb.admin/frontend/wb_admin_export.py#L1957)) replace

```py
self.out_pipe = open(self.path,"w")
```

with

```py
self.out_pipe = open(self.path,"wb")
```

Comment: I had to change `w` to `wb` in two lines: `self.out_pipe = open(path,"w")` inside function `dump_to_folder()` and `self.out_pipe = open(self.path,"w")` inside function `dump_to_file()`.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn that's exactly the functions I've referenced in the answer ;)

Comment: Indeed you are right! I just added the comment to help someone that just ignored the line numbers (like I did), pressed "Find Next" twice and ended up finding only one occurrence because on one line we have `open(path,"w")` and on the other we have `open(self.path,"w")` 

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn you're definitely right, I've edited the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you a using version 8.0.23, update to 8.0.25 or above.... it will fix this issue

Comment: I guess, you're a bit late to the party ;) See the second comment to OP.